# Mod ignored by java compiler

Tags: java

I have a problem with a program that prints a list of prime numbers, but as modulus is ignored, the program is not working. Can someone find something wrong here?

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Primos {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Dame el numero hasta el cual sacare primos");
        int hasta = entrada.nextInt();

        for(int actual = 2 ; actual <= hasta ; actual++){
            boolean primo = true;
            for(int probando = 2 ; probando < actual ; probando ++){
                double valor = (double)actual/(double)probando;
                System.out.println("1." +valor);
                valor = valor % 10;
                System.out.println("2." +valor);
                if(valor == 0){
                    primo = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(primo)
                System.out.println("El numero " + actual + " es primo");
        }
    }   
}
```

prints

```
Dame el numero hasta el cual sacare primos
3
El numero 2 es primo
1.1.5 <before mod
2.1.5 < after mod
El numero 3 es primo
```

Comment: it has casting to double, and I am getting mod of 1.5 that should be .5 and its returning 1.5

Comment: `1.5 % 10 == 1.5`... What else did you expect?

Comment: it should be 5 right?

Comment: @BaxterLopez The remainder of `11.5 / 10` or `21.5 / 10` is 1.5.  Why would that be any different for `1.5 / 10`? All % does is give you the remainder.

Comment: a % b gives you the answer to "once I have removed as many b as possible from a, how much is left?" - for example: 0.5 % 0.3 is 0.2. And 1.5 % 10 is 1.5...

Comment: Besides which, 3 is a prime number.

Comment: Why are you doing `valor = valor % 10` anyway? Try just testing `actual % probando`; if that's 0 at any point it's not a prime.

Comment: Yes, already noticed that's a mistake :/ sorry and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is wrong.  A number is prime if no number less than it divide evenly into it (ie number % factor == 0 means it's not prime)

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Dame el numero hasta el cual sacare primos");
    int hasta = entrada.nextInt();

    boolean primo = true;
    for(int factor = 2 ; primo && factor < hasta/2 ; factor++){
      primo = hasta % factor != 0;
    }
    if(primo)
      System.out.println("El numero " + actual + " es primo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [assylias's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053710/mod-ignored-by-java-compiler/19054090#comment28159756_19053710), `1.5 % 10 = 1.5`

Replace your statement

```
valor = valor % 10;
```

with

```
valor = valor - (long) valor;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first iteration, the nested for loop doesn't execute because `actual=2` is not smaller than `probando=2`.

```
for (int probando = 2; probando < actual; probando++) {
```

So your next iteration occurs where `actual=3` and `probando=2`, printing the values you see.

Comment: Thats right as 2 its a prime number, the problem is that when the second for loop works the mod is not called or its not working i dont know why

Comment: @BaxterLopez The mod is called exactly as you put it. What do you think it should be printing?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
int valor = actual % probando;
```

As `actual / probando` gives the integer division (rounding down / truncating the fraction),
`actual % probando` gives the remainder of such division:

```
12 / 7 = 1
12 % 7 = 5


(p / q) * q + (p % q) == p
```

If value is 0, `probando` is a divisor of `actual`. What you meant.